# typoscript: build URL from Page-ID and GET Parameters

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have to replace a marker on my typo3 page using typoscript to build a link to another page (i.e. another type of the same page).

For this link, I have to set the same query parameters as the current page, plus the page Id of the current page, for example `<a href="index.php?id=11&param1=abc&param2=def&type=123">`

What I have so far is to pass the QUERY_STRING as received to the following site. The problem arises when the current page's path has no `id` parameter, e.g. set by RealURL.

so what I need is a mapping like this:

```
mysite.com/about_us  
     ==>  mysite.com/index.php?id=11&type=123&L=1

mysite.com/index.php?id=33&param1=abc&param2=def&L=1
     ==>  mysite.com/index.php?id=33&param1=abc&param2=def&L=1
```

this is what I tried:

```
page.10.marks.printlink = HTML
page.10.marks.printlink.value = dummy
# For plugin pages with querystring
page.10.marks.printlink.value.data= getIndpEnv:QUERY_STRING
# For other Typo3 pages
page.10.marks.printlink.value.ifEmpty.data = page:uid
page.10.marks.printlink.value.ifEmpty.dataWrap = id=|
page.10.marks.printlink.value.wrap = <a target="_blank" href="index.php?|&type=123">print</a>
```

This works for most cases, but not if a RealURL PREVar is in place, in which case the following is mapped:

```
mysite.com/de/über_uns
  ==>  mysite.com/de/index.php?L=2&type=123
```

So, no id is passed! (presumably because RealURL replaces the `/de/` prevar by `L=2`, but doesn't set the `id`)

My question is: is there a way to simply concatenate the `page:uid` and `QUERY_STRING`? Or do I have to do some more typoscript magic?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Do you know all the GET parameters that can be set in the URL or does the solution have to be so universal that it works for any variables set in the URL? ID of the current page is always known, no matter whether RealURL is used or not.

Comment: There are usually 2-4 parameters, and I know all their names. But I figured out a universal way that attaches all the parameters and the id. See my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but please use typolink if you need links:)

```
page.10.marks.printlink = HTML
page.10.marks.printlink {
  value = linktext
  value.typolink.data = TSFE:id
  value.typolink.addQueryString = 1
  value.typolink.addQueryString.method = get
  value.typolink.additionalParams = &type=123
}
# Check for duplicate parameters and remove them
page.config.uniqueLinkVars = 1
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the `addQueryString` parameter of `typolink`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally managed to figure it out! The key lies in `insertData`. This is what I do now:

```
page.10.marks.printlink = TEXT
page.10.marks.printlink.value = id={page:uid}&{getIndpEnv:QUERY_STRING}
page.10.marks.printlink.insertData = 1

page.10.marks.printlink.wrap = <a target="_blank" href="index.php?|&type=123">print</a>

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
page.10.marks.printlink.wrap = <a target="_blank" href="index.php?|&type=123&L=1">drucken</a>
[global]
```

This will post the `id` parameter twice now and then, but with the same value, and there might be additional `&`, but it works.